# Jubula is not recognizing AUT even after it's launch

Tags: java, swing, jubula

I'm trying to test a Java Swing application using Jubula. After launching the application it asks for username and password.

I have done the AUT configuration properly but while starting AUT from Jubula ITE "Starting AUT with ID" is keep on loading even after the login dialog appears.

I tried to run it from the command prompt but the same issue. Since Jubula is not recognizing the application I couldn't able to proceed with test cases and object mapping.

Note: By default, the Jubula installation directory name is populated in my AUT "User name" text box in the login dialog (Not sure from where it's configured)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar (maybe the same) issue: it happens when an application starts with a splash-screen, where credentials must be entered before continueing.

Jubula remote-control plug-in is not getting loaded before the user is authenticated and Jubula can not connect to the application and start any test.

I solved it by developing a "password read-in" feature from disk, where it looks for an .ini file with credentials and fills and sends the form when found. Once the workbench is loaded, the RC plug-in is as well and test starts.

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you so much for your reply. My problem is something similar to "https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/490274/". I'm using java swing application which runs on IBM.  There is one solution provided in the above link as "You may start your AUT by directly specifying the jar file or the main class together with the class path in the AUT configuration. This is an additional step, but the only option if the JVM doesn't understand _JAVA_OPTIONS.". I'm not pretty sure on configuring this, if you are aware of it could you please guide me?

Comment: The solution on the linked thread is specific to starting an AUT with a batch file. How do you start your AUT?

Comment: My AUT also starts from a batch file. I have provided the path of .bat file while doing AUT configuration in jubula tool.

Comment: Additional details, I have changed jre to oracle and jubula is able to recognize the application now. But I need to use IBM jre for my AUT to make it work as expected. Any solution for this please?